# Modify $rootscope property from different controllers

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

In my rootscope I have a `visible` property which controls the visibility of a div

```
app.run(function ($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.visible = false;
});
```

Example HTML:

```
<section ng-controller='oneCtrl'>
    <button ng-click='toggle()'>toggle</button>
    <div ng-show='visible'>
        <button ng-click='toggle()'>&times;</button>
    </div>
</section>
```

Controller:

```
var oneCtrl = function($scope){
    $scope.toggle = function () {
        $scope.visible = !$scope.visible;
    };
}
```

The above section works fine, the element is shown or hide without problems. Now in the same page in a different section I try to change the `visible` variable to show the div but it doesn't work.

```
<section ng-controller='otherCtrl'>
    <button ng-click='showDiv()'>show</button>
</section>
```

Controller:

```
var otherCtrl = function($scope){
    $scope.showDiv = function () {
        $scope.visible = true;
    };
}
```

Comment: Do you have a JSFiddle of this we can see?

Comment: My actual code is bigger, here is just a quick and short version.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In AngularJS, `$scope`s prototypically inherit from their parent scope, all the way up to `$rootScope`. In JavaScript, primitive types are *overwritten* when a child changes them. So when you set `$scope.visible` in one of your controllers, the property on `$rootScope` was never touched, but rather a new `visible` property was added to the current scope.

In AngularJS, model values on the scope should always "have a dot", meaning be objects instead of primitives.

However, you can also solve your case by injecting `$rootScope`:

```js
var otherCtrl = function($scope, $rootScope){
  $scope.showDiv = function () {
    $rootScope.visible = true;
  };
}
```

Comment: I didn't want to inject $rootscope in the controller but it works.

Comment: Keeping a value in `$rootScope` is probably not the best solution. It will work in this case, as I said, but it may not be the best approach. Without more information, though, it's hard to say what the best solution would be.

Answer (score 1):

How familiar are you with the concept of $scope? It looks to me based on your code that you're maintaining two separate $scope variables called "visible" in two different scopes. Do each of your controllers have their own scopes? This is often the case, in which case you're actually editing different variables both named "visible" when you do a $scope.visible = true in different controllers.

If the visible is truly in the rootscope you can do $rootScope.visible instead of $scope.visible, but this is kind of messy.

One option is to have that "otherCtrl" code section in a directive (you should probably be doing this anyway), and then two-way-bind the directive scope to the parent scope, which you can [read up on here](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive). That way both the directive and the page controller are using the same scope object.

In order to better debug your $scope, try the Chrome plugin for Angular, called [Batarang](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive). This let's you actually traverse ALL of your scopes and see the Model laid out for you, rather than just hoping you're looking in the right place.

Comment: Thanks, I thought because $rootScope.visible was already initialized $scope.visible would be a reference to it

Comment: Nope! Each controller should have a separate $scope. $rootScope is accessible, but they're not bound the way you're describing. Except when you get into directives - then you can bind together parent/child scope variables in the way you want to use them. I would still recommend against using $rootScope directly though.

Comment: Actually, controller scopes inherit just like directive scopes, all the way up to `$rootScope`. They *are* bound the way @olanod expects; the problem is that in JavaScript, primitive types are overwritten in children when using prototypical inheritance, which `$scope`s do. But I recommend against using `$rootScope` in this case too - services are probably a better choice.